# Do you know why is appearing "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this storeRegistration() to create a new registration. But it's appearing an error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

in this foreach of the storeRegistration():

```
if (isset($request->participant_question)) {
    foreach( $request->participant_question as $key => $question ) { // error is here
        $answer = Answer::create([
            'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$key],
            'participant_id' => $participants[$key]->id,
            'answer' => $request->participant_question[$key],
        ]);
    }
}
```

This foreach above is to insert in the answers table the user answer to each question.

Do you know why it is appearing that error? The code seems correct.

StoreRegistration():

```
public function storeRegistration(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
{

    $allParticipants = Conference::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;
    $user = Auth::user();

    $rules = [];
    $messages = [];

    if ($allParticipants == 1) {
        $rules["participant_name.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';
        $rules["participant_surname.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {

        $total = Session::get('total');

        $registration = Registration::create([
            'conference_id' => $id,
            'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
            'status' => ($total > 0) ? 'I' : 'C',
        ]);

        $participants = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++) {
            $name = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_name[$i] : '';
            $surname = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_surname[$i] : '';
            $participants[] = Participant::create([
                'name' => $name,
                'surname' => $surname,
                'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                'registration_type_id' => $request->rtypes[$i]

            ]);
        }

        if (isset($request->participant_question)) {
            foreach( $request->participant_question as $key => $question ) {
                $answer = Answer::create([
                    'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$key],
                    'participant_id' => $participants[$key]->id,
                    'answer' => $request->participant_question[$key],
                ]);
            }
        }
        return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]).'#myTickets');
    }
    else{
        //dd($validator);
        dd($validator->errors());
    }
}
```

Html form that the user fills:

```
  <form method="post" id="registration_form" action="http://proj.test/conference/1/conf-title/registration/storeRegistration">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="participant_question">Phone?</label>

        <input type='text' name='participant_question' class='form-control' required>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="participant_question">Receive notifications?</label>
        <div class='form-check'>
          <input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='yes' class='form-check-input' required>    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">yes</label>
        </div> 
        <div class='form-check'>
          <input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='no' class='form-check-input' required>    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">no</label>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="participant_question">File</label>

        <input type='file' name='participant_question' class='form-control' required>
        <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]"  value="1">
        <input type="hidden" value="3" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
      </div>

      <input type="hidden" value=""  name="participant_name[]"/>
      <input type="hidden" value="" name="participant_surname[]"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="rtypes[]" value="2"/>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="participant_question">Phone?</label>
        <input type='text' name='participant_question' class='form-control' required>
        <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
        <input type="hidden"  value="1"  name="participant_question_id[]"/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="participant_question">Receive notifications?</label>
        <div class='form-check'>
          <input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='yes' class='form-check-input' required>    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">yes</label>
        </div> 
        <div class='form-check'>
          <input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='no' class='form-check-input' required>    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">no</label>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="participant_question">File</label>
        <input type='file' name='participant_question' class='form-control' required>
        <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" value="3" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
      </div>

      <input type="submit"class="btn btn-primary" value="Store Registration"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Try `$question = $request->participant_question;` then `foreach($question as ...)`. Are you sure `$request->participant_question;` is an array btw?

Comment: Thanks, but this "            if (isset($request->participant_question)) {
" remains"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really anybody's guess what the contents of `$request->participant_question` will be.

You are using the same name for various form fields, sometimes as an array but sometimes not:

- Phone (this is not set to be an array)
- Notifications
- File

You need to use unique name attributes to make sure they contain what you think they contain.

Comment: Thanks, but this form fields are custom questions, the user can create any question, a question can be "Phone?", but also any other like "Email?", etc.  So maybe is necessary that the form fields  have the same name.

Comment: @johnW How would you distinguish them afterwards? At the very least they all need to be set as arrays in the form, now `Phone` for example is not.

Comment: Thanks, change all questions to participant_question[] now appears "Undefined offset: 2
" on "'participant_id' => $participants[$key]->id,".

Comment: In:"$participant_question = $request->participant_question;

            foreach( $participant_question as $key => $question ) {
                $answer = Answer::create([
                    'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$key],
                    'participant_id' => $participants[$key]->id,
                    'answer' => $request->participant_question[$key],
                ]);
            }".

Comment: The            "dd($participants);""
 shows "array:2 [▼
  0 => Participant {#302 ▶}
  1 => Participant {#304 ▶}
]"".

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. Foreach works only on arrays and objects, and **will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable**.

So before the foreach :

```
$participant_question = $request->participant_question;
```

Then you can use :

```
foreach( $participant_question as $key => $question ) {
    ...
}
```

And I will rewrite it, but :

> Foreach works only on arrays and objects

So be sure that `$request->participant_question` is an `array` OR an `object`

Comment: Thanks, but same error with " $participant_question = $request->participant_question;
            foreach( $participant_question as $key => $question ) {
                $answer = Answer::create([
                    'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$key],
                    'participant_id' => $participants[$key]->id,
                    'answer' => $request->participant_question[$key],
                ]);
            }".

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($participant_question);`?

Comment: It appears "Undefined variable: participant_question".

Comment: Did you make `$participant_question = $request->participant_question;` BEFORE `var_dump($participant_question);`?

Comment: Why would setting it to another variable make a difference?

Comment: Like this "
            $participant_question = $request->participant_question;
            var_dump($participant_question);"  appears "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
".

Comment: @johnW Now you are debugging, so comment the part of your code with problem and just check what kind of data you have in `$request->participant_question` :)

Answer (score 1):

Before **foreach** check if **$request->participant_question** is array.

```
if (is_array($request->participant_question)) {
    foreach( $request->participant_question as $key => $question ) { // error is here
        $answer = Answer::create([
            'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$key],
            'participant_id' => $participants[$key]->id,
            'answer' => $request->participant_question[$key],
        ]);
    }
}
```